# AVR simulator to run the whole program?

Tags: avr

As the title suggests, i wonder if there is any AVR simulator who can run all the program by once. AVR studio only does it step by step, and it is taking me more to time to check the efficiency of a program rather than write it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Er... only step by step? I'm fairly sure there's a "Go" menu option that'll just run instead of step...?

Comment: where is this command on avr studio 5 specifically? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you have small tutorial on using simulator: http://youtu.be/zGKaJy-3JgI?t=1m22s
You can choose "Start debugging" or press F5 to run code.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit F5 if you haven't set any breakpoints then the application should run without any stops but in this mode you can not see any variables and processor' state.